# Programming a simple color scheme generator

Tags: c#, colors, controls, generator, color-theory

we are developing a website cms in C# and want to integrate / develop a small and simple color scheme generator as like as [colorschemedesigner.com](http://colorschemedesigner.com) (of course simplier) to automatically suggest harmonizing template colors (for body background, text, heading etc.).

There are 6 methods for color creation on that website. We would like to reprogram the logic of the "accented analogic" algorithm.

Does anyone know how to easily realize this, or where we could find more information about this topic. How to programatically find a set of harmonizing colors for a given base?

Or are there already some third-party controls out there that could do the job?
E.g. an advanced advanced advanced color picker or some thing.

Daniel

Comment: http://colorschemedesigner.com/#0L62Aw0w0w0w0 would be a direct example of what to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe's Kuler is pretty good at this. If you want to look at the theory that governs how Kuler creates colour schemes you can look at examples like [this on colour theory](http://myworldofcolour.wordpress.com/category/theory/).

[image: analogous colour scheme creation]

You could begin by creating a colourwheel then using the scheme definitions in this link -- or others -- to work out which colours to choose based on their position on the wheel (e.g. the analogous scheme above).

Comment: And it's also an area prone to heated disagreement in detail :)

Answer (score 3):

I found this useful in the past.  [Random Pastel Colour Generator](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/07/random-pastel-colour-generator.html)

Code in c# can be found on the page above.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool link. While the code itself produces rather random colors, it points to http://www.devwebpro.com/25-popular-color-scheme-and-palette-generators/ with great resources and further links.